# GoLang pubsub server stops listening to new channel subscriptions

Tags: go, redis, publish-subscribe, goland

I have a redis pubsub connection in my go websocket app, so whenever a client connects and subscribes to a channel, it listens and sends message.
However, say Client 1 is subscribed to channel `X`, the pubsub starts listening and receiving messages from it.

Now, Client 1 also subscribes to channel `Y`, so the server should also listen to messages from that channel, however it stops listening to `X` and only to `Y`.

```golang
    for {
        switch v := gPubSubConn.Receive().(type) {
        case redis.Message:
            log.Printf("Received message from %s", v.Channel)
            subscriptions := ps.GetSubscriptions(v.Channel, nil)
            for _, sub := range subscriptions {
                if v.Channel == types.TaskResults {
                    go sendTaskResultMessage(v.Data, sub)
                } else if v.Channel == types.TaskCount {
                    go sendTaskCountMessage(v.Data, sub)
                }
            }
        case redis.Subscription:
            log.Printf("Subscription message: %s: %s %d\n", v.Channel, v.Kind, v.Count)
        case error:
            log.Println("Error pub/sub, delivery stopped")
            return
        }
```

Here's an example log output

```sh
go-1  | New Client is connected, total:  1
go-1  | 2022/02/16 17:36:03 signature is invalid
go-1  | 2022/02/16 17:36:03 Subscription message: task_count: subscribe 1
go-1  | 2022/02/16 17:36:06 Received message from task_count
go-1  | 2022/02/16 17:36:06 Received message from task_count
go-1  | New Client is connected, total:  2
go-1  | 2022/02/16 17:36:14 signature is invalid
go-1  | 2022/02/16 17:36:14 Subscription message: task_results: subscribe 1
go-1  | 2022/02/16 17:36:16 Received message from task_count
go-1  | 2022/02/16 17:36:16 Received message from task_results
go-1  | 2022/02/16 17:36:16 Received message from task_results
go-1  | 2022/02/16 17:36:21 Received message from task_results
go-1  | 2022/02/16 17:36:21 Received message from task_results
go-1  | 2022/02/16 17:36:26 Received message from task_results
go-1  | 2022/02/16 17:36:26 Received message from task_results
go-1  | 2022/02/16 17:36:31 Received message from task_results
go-1  | 2022/02/16 17:36:31 Received message from task_results
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Edited as per comment:

```golang
type PubSub struct {
    Clients       []Client
    Subscriptions []Subscription
}

type Client struct {
    Id         string
    Connection *websocket.Conn
}

type Message struct {
    Action  string          `json:"action"`
    Topic   string          `json:"topic"`
    Message json.RawMessage `json:"message"`
    Token   string          `json:"token"`
}

type Subscription struct {
    Topic  string
    Client *Client
    UserId string
}

func (ps *PubSub) GetSubscriptions(topic string, client *Client) []Subscription {
    var subscriptionList []Subscription

    for _, subscription := range ps.Subscriptions {
        if client != nil {
            if subscription.Client.Id == client.Id && subscription.Topic == topic {
                subscriptionList = append(subscriptionList, subscription)
            }
        } else {
            if subscription.Topic == topic {
                subscriptionList = append(subscriptionList, subscription)
            }
        }
    }
    return subscriptionList
}
```

Here's my websocket handler

```golang
func websocketHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    gRedisConn, err := gRedisConn()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    gPubSubConn = &redis.PubSubConn{Conn: gRedisConn.Get()}
    upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true

    }
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    client := pubsub.Client{
        Id:         autoId(),
        Connection: conn,
    }

    // add this client into the list
    ps.AddClient(client)

    fmt.Println("New Client is connected, total: ", len(ps.Clients))

    for {
        messageType, p, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Something went wrong", err)
            ps.RemoveClient(client)
            log.Println("total clients and subscriptions ", len(ps.Clients), len(ps.Subscriptions))
            return
        }
        go listenToMessages()
        ps.HandleReceiveMessage(client, messageType, p, gPubSubConn)
    }
}
func (ps *PubSub) HandleReceiveMessage(client Client, messageType int, payload []byte, gPubSubConn *redis.PubSubConn) *PubSub {
    m := Message{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(payload, &m)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("This is not correct message payload")
        return ps
    }
    switch m.Action {
    case PUBLISH:
        ps.Publish(m.Topic, m.Message, nil)
    case SUBSCRIBE:
        ps.Subscribe(&client, m.Topic, gPubSubConn, m.Token)
    case UNSUBSCRIBE:
        fmt.Println("Client want to unsubscribe the topic", m.Topic, client.Id)
    default:
        break
    }

    return ps
}
func (ps *PubSub) Subscribe(client *Client, topic string, gPubSubConn *redis.PubSubConn, token string) *PubSub {
    clientSubs := ps.GetSubscriptions(topic, client)
    if len(clientSubs) > 0 {
        return ps
    }
    userId := utils.GetUser(token)
    newSubscription := Subscription{
        Topic:  topic,
        Client: client,
        UserId: userId,
    }
    ps.Subscriptions = append(ps.Subscriptions, newSubscription)
    if err := gPubSubConn.Subscribe(topic); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    return ps
}
```

Comment: Included the function there.

Comment: I included the websocket handler where the subscription is handled.

Comment: (1) Run the application with the [race detector](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector). I expect that you will find several problems.    (2) Previous subscriptions are ignored because websocketHandler sets gPubSubConn to a new pubsub conn with no subscriptions.  The previous pubsub conn is leaked.

Comment: Ah, I see, I didn't know the websocketHandler would be creating new pubsub connection all the time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea how to use race detector, however I created my connection in main(), and it works, if you want to post it as solution, I'll accept it.

Comment: My previous comment links to the instructions for running the race detector.  If you are using `go build` to build your app, then use `go build -race` to build with the race detector.  If you are using `go run` to build and run your application, then use `go run -race` to build and run your application with the race detector.  Super simple.  Will find many bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate issue is caused by this line in `websocketHandler`:

```
gPubSubConn = &redis.PubSubConn{Conn: gRedisConn.Get()}
```

This line replaces the current pubsub connection with a new connection.  The new connection does not have any subscriptions.  The previous connection is leaked.

Create the pubsub connection once at application startup.

The application has at least one data race.  Run the application with the [race detector](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector) and fix the reported problems.